# Tools that turn regular phrases into regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I know there are a lot of tools that allow you to create regular expressions and test regular phrases against them, but is there a tool that allows you to type just a regular phrase or word, etc and it will generate the regular expression for you.  For example, typing:

xyz555.. would generate the correct regular expression.  It may not be the most ideal expression, but it would be a useful learning tool.

Comment: what would the correct regular expression for `xyz555...` be in your opinion?

Comment: Lol, I am new to regular expressions, so that is why something like this would be helpful if it was possible or existed.

Comment: What would stop the tool from just always returning `.*`? Or simply the word itself (with special regex characters escaped)? Even if the user could specify a whitelist (words that should match) and a blacklist (words that shouldn't), the tool could simply return the words of the white list ORed together (i.e. `word1|word2|...|wordn`).

Comment: Then please just explain what you mean by `xyz555...`? "A string starting with `xyz` and followed by an arbitrary number of fives"?

Comment: Otto:  It was just an example.  Adam's answer explained to be that it is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because such analysis can't be done deterministically. It's impossible to take a single sample (or any *particular* number of samples) and generate a pattern.

For example, your example data could mean three alphabetic characters followed by three numeric characters...

...or it could be *any* number of alphabetic characters followed by three numerics

...or three alphabetic followed by three '5' characters.

It's impossible to determine exactly what the pattern is when more than one pattern fits the data.

Comment: @Adam: Can you explain in what you mean in a little more detail.  In my example, I actually mean 3 alphabetic characters followed by three numeric characters.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I realize that's what you mean; my point is that the application would have no way of *knowing* that's what you mean. It could come up with a theoretically unlimited number of different patterns that would all fit that data, but only one of them would be right.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I guess one you would have to be really specific on what you mean when you create a phrase? But it seems like hard work.

Comment: @Xaisoft: The only way to do it would be to allow the user to specify exactly what the pattern is...which would simply be creating a new regular expression language.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Well if we humans don't really know what you mean by `xyz`, how can you expect a computer to know that?

Comment: @Otto:  That's pretty much the answer I was looking for.